# How to define where condition (ex: userid != 0) in this below query?

Tags: mysql, joomla

How to define where condition in this below query?form the database except the zero value need to shown

```
 private function totalVisitedPagesPerUser() {
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*), " . $this->_db->quoteName('customer_name') . "," . 
                     "\n MAX(". $this->_db->quoteName('visit_timestamp') . ")," .                        $this->_db->quoteName('browser') . "," .
                     $this->_db->quoteName('os') . "," .
                     $this->_db->quoteName('session_id_person') . "," . 
                     $this->_db->quoteName('ip') . "," .
                     "\n SUM(" . $this->_db->quoteName('impulse') . ")," .
                     $this->_db->quoteName('geolocation') .
                     "\n FROM ( SELECT * FROM #__realtimeanalytics_serverstats " . $this->whereQuery . " ORDER BY  `visit_timestamp` DESC) AS INTABLE" .
                     $this->whereQuery .
                     "\n GROUP BY " . $this->_db->quoteName('session_id_person') .
                     "\n ORDER BY " . $this->_db->quoteName('customer_name');
            $this->_db->setQuery($query);
            $results = $this->_db->loadRowList();
            if ($this->_db->getErrorNum()) {
                throw new JRealtimeException(JText::sprintf('COM_JREALTIME_ERROR_RECORDS', $this->_db->getErrorMsg()), 'error');
            }
            return $results;
        }
```

Comment: anyone there to solve this

Comment: is your question: whether to add in the sub query or in the main query? could you please clarify?

Comment: add in the sub query... in database id where mingled with zero so I need to show except zero value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can prepare where condition variable by checking conditions before query start, than append that variable at that point like:

```
$wherecondtion = "Where 1=1";
if($condition1){$wherecondtion."AND (add required filter 1)"}
if($condition2){$wherecondtion."AND (add required filter 2)"}
```

your subquery will be like:

```
"( SELECT * FROM #__realtimeanalytics_serverstats " . $wherecondtion . " ORDER BY  `visit_timestamp` DESC)"
```

Is this the thing you needed or something different thing?